# YouTube API channel's videos list

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently trying to make a site which uploads all the videos from specific playlist of some channel. Like list of videos. And I found this video - [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jdqsiFw74Jk). And that's what I have now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels",{
      part : 'contentDetails', 
      forUsername : 'CHANNEL_NAME',
      key: 'MY_KEY'},
      function(data) {
        $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
          console.log(item);
        })
      }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I have nothing in console, though judging by `console.log(item)` something must be there, at least `undefined`. And even when I write just `console.log('hi')` I still have nothing. I just can't understand what's wrong. Anyway, I'd be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to retrieve videos of a specific channel. You should use `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search` endpoint instead of `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels`. So, I provided an example with `channelId` and `type` parameters; (`type` parameter can be `video, playlist, channel`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",{
      part : 'snippet', 
      channelId : 'UCR5wZcXtOUka8jTA57flzMg',
      type : 'video',
      key: 'MyKey'},
      function(data) {
        $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
          console.log(item);
        })
      }
  );
});
```

This will get you videos of a channel. If you want to get playlists of channel just change `type` parameter to `playlist`. Here is the official [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).

Comment: thanks, it works, but using this way I don't know how to make list of the videos, like `<ul class="results"><li><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEO_ID"></iframe></li></ul>`. I know that I get videoId from `item.id.videoId`, but I don't what to do next. I'll be very happy if you help me.

Answer (score 3):

So if anyone wonders, here's finished code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search",{
      part : 'snippet', 
      channelId : 'CHANNEL_ID', // You can get one from Advanced settings on YouTube
      type : 'video',
      key: 'YOUR_KEY'},
      function(data) {
        $.each( data.items, function( i, item ) {
          $('#results').append('<li>https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + item.id.videoId + '</li>');
        })
      }
  );
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul id="results"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```