# How can I get the list of videos of a YouTube channel using YouTube API?

Tags: youtube

I'm creating an application for education. This app can have many channels.

When admin adds a channel, he can request to retrieval of the list of videos of that channel.

I want to use YouTube API V3 for this purpose. But I'm stuck.

The [Channels](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) does not have a way to get video results. The [Videos](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API does not have a `channelId` as its parameters.

As specified in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48052738/youtube-api-channels-videos-list) question, I should use [Search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) API which does have a `channelId` parameter. But it seems that it's only limited to 500 results:

> The channelId parameter indicates that the API response should only contain resources created by the channel.
>
> Note: Search results are constrained to a maximum of 500 videos if your request specifies a value for the channelId parameter and sets the type parameter value to video, but it does not also set one of the forContentOwner, forDeveloper, or forMine filters.

So, I'm stuck at this point. I want to be able to retrieve the list of **ALL** videos of a given channel.

Comment: Can't you use the `forContentOwner` filter?

Comment: @TimRoberts, no. That filter is meant for applications that want to act on behalf of a content owner. It requires OAuth I guess and it's not reflecting my need. I'm not creating a tool for content owners. I'm creating an internal tool for our teachers.

Comment: If you're not authorizing, then you are limited to 500.  That's just the way it is.

Comment: I can create an authorized request. But using my own API key, not on behalf of the content creator.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74579030) solves your problem.